# Javascript: Detect a dynamic tab after clicking browser back button

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-tabs

I have the following tab setup:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
  <li class="active"><a href="#search">Search</a></li>
  <li><a href="#search_other">Search other</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active"  id="search">
      <%= render 'search/search' %>
    </div>

    <div class="tab-pane" id="search_other">
      <%= render 'results/search_other' %>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
  $('#myTab a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).tab('show');
  });

  // store the currently selected tab in the hash value
  $("ul.nav-tabs > li > a").on("shown.bs.tab", function(e) {
    var id = $(e.target).attr("href").substr(1);
    window.location.hash = id;
  });

  // on load of the page: switch to the currently selected tab
  var hash = window.location.hash;
  $('#myTab a[href="' + hash + '"]').tab('show');
</script>

<script>
  $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    history.pushState(null, null, $(this).attr('href'));
  });
</script>
```

Each tab contains a search form and after a search is submitted it redirects to the results page. When I'm at the results page I want to click on the browser back button and trigger an event with this function:

```
window.onpopstate = function() {
 alert("clicked back button");
}; history.pushState({}, '');
```

the `window.onpopstate` function works from every other page, except when I'm trying to go back to the tab page after a search. I'm guessing for some reason it's not recognizing the tab.
Any ideas on how to make this work?

Comment: why dont you use localStorage to store the active tab for reference.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Srinivas.. can you be more specific on how to implement the `localStorage` and then the `window.onpopstate` ??

Answer (score 0):

Try Something like this, in document ready function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function(e) {
        localStorage.setItem('activeTab', $(e.target).attr('href'));
    });
    var activeTab = localStorage.getItem('activeTab');
    if(activeTab){
        $('#myTab a[href="' + activeTab + '"]').tab('show');
    }
});
```

Code for window.popstate:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // add a hash to the URL when the user clicks on a tab
  $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('click', function(e) {
    history.pushState(null, null, $(this).attr('href'));
  });
  // navigate to a tab when the history changes
  window.addEventListener("popstate", function(e) {
    var activeTab = $('[href=' + location.hash + ']');
    if (activeTab.length) {
      activeTab.tab('show');
    } else {
      $('.nav-tabs a:first').tab('show');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working either. I added your code along with the `window.onpopstate` and the alert shows on any page I click the browser back button, except for when I want to return from the search results to the tab.

Comment: i have updated the answer according to your approach. can you create an example in codepen or jsbin so that it is easier to fix the issue